# Filter copying one file to multiple in ant

Tags: ant

I have an ant task that does a filter copy I call it multiple times only changing the parameter. This is to create properties files for various environments.

I want to simplify the calling target so i can do less copy and paste.

Here is the calling target

```
<target name="create_local_property_files" depends="clean,prepare">
    <!-- create first machine property files -->
    <antcall target="property.filter.copy" inheritAll="false">
        <param name="tmp.dom" value="machine1" />
    </antcall>
    <!-- create second machine property files -->
    <antcall target="property.filter.copy" inheritAll="false">
        <param name="tmp.dom" value="machine2" />
    </antcall>
            [...] <!-- to the n'th machine property file -->
</target>
```

I would like to make one call and pass in a list of machines. Any suggestions?

Here is the filter copy target for completeness

```
<target name="property.filter.copy">
    <copy todir="${local.property.file.dir}" failonerror="true" verbose="true" overwrite="true">
        <filterset>
            <!-- Uses the same filters files as scripts -->
            <filtersfile file="${property.variables.dir}/${tmp.dom}.properties" />
        </filterset>
        <fileset dir="${property.file.dir}">
            <include name="cnmp.properties" />
            <include name="cnmp.jdo.properties" />
        </fileset>
        <!-- Deployment script looks for hostname.rest_of_filename-->
        <globmapper from="*" to="${tmp.dom}.*" />
    </copy>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using [macrodefs](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/macrodef.html) for repeated code segments

```
<project name="demo" default="copy">

    <macrodef name="propertyFilterCopy">
        <attribute name="tmp.dom"/>
        <attribute name="local.property.file.dir" default="build/properties"/>
        <attribute name="property.variables.dir"  default="build/variables"/>
        <attribute name="property.file.dir"       default="build/files"/>
        <sequential>
            <copy todir="@{local.property.file.dir}" failonerror="true" verbose="true" overwrite="true">
                <filterset>
                    <filtersfile file="@{property.variables.dir}/@{tmp.dom}.properties" />
                </filterset>
                <fileset dir="@{property.file.dir}">
                    <include name="cnmp.properties" />
                    <include name="cnmp.jdo.properties" />
                </fileset>
                <globmapper from="*" to="@{tmp.dom}.*" />
            </copy>
        </sequential>
    </macrodef>

    <target name="copy" depends="gen-data">
        <propertyFilterCopy tmp.dom="machine1"/>
        <propertyFilterCopy tmp.dom="machine2"/>
    </target>

    <target name="gen-data">
        <mkdir dir="build/properties"/>
        <mkdir dir="build/variables"/>
        <mkdir dir="build/files"/>
        <echo file="build/files/cnmp.properties">x=1</echo>
        <echo file="build/files/cnmp.jdo.properties">x=1</echo>
        <echo file="build/variables/machine1.properties">x=1</echo>
        <echo file="build/variables/machine2.properties">x=1</echo>
    </target>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="build"/>
    </target>

</project>
```

A second advantage of macrodefs is that they can be packaged as [antlibs](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/antlib.html) which further increase the portability of re-usable build logic.

Comment: For those who know ant syntax less well, observe that @{id} is an attribute, different from ${id} which is a property.

Answer (score 0):

There are some loops implemented in [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/index.html) which should do the job nicely.

Have a look for instance to the [`foreach`](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/foreach.html) task.